# How to add together the values in an array from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to add together values generated from a MySQL query but the total I'm getting doesn't seem to add up. Here's my code:

```
$top_score = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT 1ET FROM scoring_data WHERE 
Competition='$competition' AND Club='$row[Club]' AND Team='$row[Team]' ORDER BY 
1ET DESC LIMIT 0, 3")); 
echo (array_sum($top_score)/10) ;
```

I have two values entered into 1ET for that specific query (competition, club and team): 6 and 3. The total I should get is 9, but the total is coming out as 12...

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array isn't structured how you expect it to be:

```
print_r($top_score);
```

Maybe do it in the query:

```
SELECT SUM(1ET)/10 AS top_score FROM scoring_data WHERE
    Competition='$competition' AND Club='{$row['Club']}' AND Team='{$row['Team']}'
    ORDER BY 1ET DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Sorry, both the values are the same, I copied it out incorrectly here.

Comment: I'm new to PHP and so not quite following you, do you mean replace (array_sum($top_score) with print_r($top_score) ?

Comment: I edited.  `print_r()` is to show you what the array looks like.  Just do it in the query.